# How can I add my own custom permission across the Android system?

Tags: android, android-permissions, user-permissions

How can I add my own custom permission across the Android system?
how to apply for custom permission in a single app?
permission declaration here

```
 <permission android:name="com.testpackage.mypermission" 
    android:label="my_permission" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
```

And I call my permission with

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.testpackage.mypermission" />
```

Can I declare and used within single manifest?

Answer (score 1):

Apps can define their own custom permissions and request custom permissions from other apps by defining  elements. However, you should carefully assess whether it is necessary for your app to do so.

1. If you are designing a suite of apps that expose functionality to one another, try to design the apps so that each permission is defined only once. You must do this if the apps are not all signed with the same certificate. Even if the apps are all signed with the same certificate, it's a best practice to define each permission once only.
2. If the functionality is only available to apps signed with the same signature as the providing app, you may be able to avoid defining custom permissions by using signature checks. When one of your apps makes a request of another of your apps, the second app can verify that both apps are signed with the same certificate before complying with the request.
   For more detail [click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining#custom-recommendations)

Answer (score -1):

From [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining):
To enforce your own permissions, you must first declare them in your AndroidManifest.xml using one or more  elements.

For example, an app that wants to control who can start one of its activities could declare a permission for this operation as follows:

```
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.myapp" >

    <permission
      android:name="com.example.myapp.permission.DEADLY_ACTIVITY"
      android:label="@string/permlab_deadlyActivity"
      android:description="@string/permdesc_deadlyActivity"
      android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.COST_MONEY"
      android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Comment: so how can I apply this permission for my all activity

Comment: What is "my all activity"? You declare permission for application

Comment: my all activity means the activites that has in my app

Comment: You cannot manage permission for every `Activity` in your app. Permission declares for whole `Application`. But if you want to do have permission for single Activities, you need to implement it by yourself, without Android system permissions